# Before insert trigger in mysql giving issue when insert is fired from Java code

Tags: java, mysql, triggers

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `classdost`.`tr_xyz_media`
BEFORE INSERT ON classdost.xyz_media
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE t_id INT(20);

IF NEW.id < 5000000 THEN

INSERT INTO xyz_media_temp (insert_date) VALUES(CURDATE());
SELECT MAX(xyz_media_temp.id) INTO t_id FROM xyz_media_temp;

SET New.id = t_id;

END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I have this trigger in MySQL this is running fine  when I fire any Insert query in PHPMyadmin but when same Insert is fired from java code it is not executing. I tried changing the code made all request as Ajax with async: false and then I found out that that the earlier requests are still running in background and my later request is giving exception as no ID is returned from database yet.

What can be done to avoid this issue?

Comment: I suggest to add a new `insert_date` field of type `date`, and alter the `id` field to an a auto incremented primary key in your `classdost.xyz_media` table.

Comment: selecting max in this way, at times, will not match the correct record, due to successive insertions by others.

Comment: actually the ID column of classdost.xyz_media was auto increment only but to run this trigger we had to change that.

Answer (score 0):

If you say requests are still running in background, then it is possible that your table is locked (MyISAM tables), and you cannot modify it.

See if table is locked using this query -

```
SHOW OPEN TABLES FROM database_name;
```

This query will show you open tables, whicj cannot be edited (INSERT, UPDATE or etc.). Then check you Java application, find code that locks tables.